# Unable to create a class on Parse server. Getting error code 1 - internal server error ... how can I fix this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-platform

I just deployed parse on heroku, and I tried to create a test object from my demo ios app, but the operation fails citing internal server error (code 1). How can I resolve this? There doesn't seem to be a way to report this to parse being a new customer.

Here's my swift2 code in the viewDidLoad method -

```
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "Test")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        print(error?.description)
    }
```

Error description -

```
[Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)
Optional("Error Domain=Parse Code=1 \"{\"code\":1,\"message\":\"Internal server error.\"}\" UserInfo={error={\"code\":1,\"message\":\"Internal server error.\"}, NSLocalizedDescription={\"code\":1,\"message\":\"Internal server error.\"}, code=1}")
```

Comment: Can you upload stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redeployed parse to heroku, as a new app, and everything started to work.

Comment: Good that you found your solution :)

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue. I redeployed parse to heroku as a new app and I still get the same error. Any suggestions?